# exclude pages in custom menu

Tags: menus, wp-query

I am creating a custom theme for wordpress, which will have a settings page. i am adding the option to exclude pages from the navigation, which will simply work on the page id separated by a ","

here is the code i have so far:

```
    <ul class="tabs">
<?php
    $exmenuitems = get_option('exmenuitems');
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query (array (
    'post__not_in' => array($exmenuitems),
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'showposts' => $menuitems
));
 while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
<?php $slug = basename(get_permalink());?>   
<li><a href="#<?php echo $slug; ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

this works fine excluding just 1 page id. but when i try and exclude more than 1 id it doesn't work, only the first id in the text input will get excluded and the other remain visible.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Does your `$exmenuitems` contains an array of page Ids?

Comment: yes it currently has 3 id's

Comment: May be you should use `'post__not_in' => $exmenuitems` because it's already an array.

Comment: `showposts` should contain an int value and it's deprecated, instead you should use `posts_per_page`, http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to explode your list of page ID's using the [explode function](http://www.php.net/explode).

Something like;

```
<?php
    $exmenuitems = explode(",",get_option('exmenuitems'));
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query (array (
    'post__not_in' => $exmenuitems,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'showposts' => $menuitems
));
```

I'd recommend using the [WordPress Menu building functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and admin interface. Its much more intuitive for end users to build their navigation menus via drag n drop that using page ID's.

Comment: i have tried the explode fnuction and doesn't seem to work. when i echo it out i just get "array"

Comment: cheers guys solved!

Comment: How did you solve it, would you mind to share ?

Comment: i did what you said and removed the array from the 'post__not_in' and also used the explode function as Dale stated.